# Does Q ever actually lie?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-q

In the episode [Deja-Q](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Deja_Q_(episode)), Picard openly accuses Q of being dishonest:

> Q: I have no powers. Q the ordinary.
>
> PICARD: Q the liar. Q the misanthrope.

And in the DS9 episode [Q-Less](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Q-Less_(episode)), [Vash](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vash) claims that Q was known as "the god of lies" on at least one planet in the Gamma Quadrant

> And they weren't exactly thrilled to see you on Brax either. What did they call you? The God of Lies?

However, I can't recall any specific instance of Q being dishonest. He was far from benevolent most of the time and certainly didn't share ALL of his knowledge with the lesser races he encountered but, to my knowledge, he never lied. So why would Picard and others claim he was a liar?

Comment: Apparently Memory Alpha has pages on [Lie](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Lie) and [Liar](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Liar). Because why not.

Comment: They do and both articles mention the "god of lies" bit but I'm interested in actual instances where Q says or does something dishonest

Comment: Define **lie**. If an omission is a lie, Q does tend to omit things.

Comment: Yeah, my comment doesn't answer your question. I just thought it was interesting.

Comment: You could argue that his "omnipotence" claim is a lie ("Deja Q"), since he presumably couldn't destroy the rest of the Q with a thought. Maybe he means omnipotence as far as non-Q go.

Answer (score 11):

On Q's second visit to the Enterprise, he tells a complete untruth.

> **PICARD:** *Pay off your wager.*
>
> **Q:** ***I recall no wager!***
>
> <sub><sup>[TNG: Hide and Q](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/111.htm)</sup></sub>

During his third visit, he lies again since (we later learn) humanity has remained on trial throughout the entire voyage of the Enterprise-D

> **RIKER:** *The good times? The first time we met you, you put us on trial for the crimes of humanity.*
>
> **Q:** ***Of which you were exonerated.***
>
> <sub><sup>[TNG: Q, Who?](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/142.htm)</sup></sub>

He tells a fib in his 6th encounter, stating that Amanda's parents died in an accident when in fact they were murdered.

> **TROI:** *What happened to Amanda's parents?*
>
> **Q:** ***They died in an accident.***
>
> <sub><sup>[TNG: True Q](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/232.htm)</sup></sub>

He lies to Vash in *TNG: Q Less.* Clearly the inhabitants of Brax hate his guts.

> **VASH:** *You're the one who almost got me killed on Errikang Seven. And they weren't exactly thrilled to see you on Brax either. What did they call you? The God of Lies?*
>
> **Q:** ***They meant it affectionately.***
>
> <sub><sup>[DS9: Q-less](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/407.htm)</sup></sub>

He lies to Janeway in *VOY: The Q and the Grey*. There's no evidence that he's actually ordered anything at all from the kitchen.

> **JANEWAY:** *Janeway to security. Intruder alert.*
>
> **Q:** *There's no need to call room service, Kathy. **I've already ordered.***
>
> <sub><sup>[The Q and the Grey](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/306.htm)</sup></sub>

Comment: To be fair, we don't know that they didn't mean it affectionately

Comment: I''ll give you the first one. Q was trying to buy time by lying about forgetting the wager. The third one is dubious. They DID die in an accident regardless of the underlying cause. The second point is murky as the "trial" that Q was referring to seems to be development and evolution. Also, the Q were not going to destroy humanity, humanity-specifically Picard-was.

Comment: @geewhiz - It's pretty clear that the "accident" was no accident and that the Braxians didn't mean it affectionately.

Comment: Concerning the first one, maybe Q's memory isn't like it used to be.

Comment: @Valorum I was joking about the Braxians. Good answer!

Comment: @HamSandwich I feel more like it was a "say whatever you have to to get them to play" moment and it slipped his mind later because they are SO inferior

Comment: I was kidding around. Q's memory is presumably infallible.

Comment: The last two seem to be more Q being snarky and humorous than actually lying.

Comment: @JoshuaZ - A lie is a lie is a lie....

Comment: @JoshuaZ - Also, if someone told me they'd ordered room service, I'd be quite disappointed to find out that they hadn't.

Comment: @Valorum, So you are interpreting "lie" to include when someone says something literally false but with the intent that the person saying it knows that the person they are saying it to knows it isn't true? That seems to make much sarcasm essentially lies. I don't think that's a standard definition.

Comment: @JoshuaZ - I'm classifying it as *any intentional untruth*.